# Ошибка подключения к вебсокету

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Хочу подрубиться к вебсокету по логин паролю. Ругается на tls.

```
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1088:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38)
```

Добавил в начале кода обход этого сообщение, все равно такая же ошибка.

```
require('https').globalAgent.options.ca = require('ssl-root-cas/latest').create();
var ws = require('nodejs-websocket')

var name = 'xxx'

var password = 'xxx'

var options = {

    extraHeaders: {
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + new Buffer(name+ ':' + password).toString('base64')

    }
}

var conn = ws.connect('wss://xxx.ru:8001',options)



conn.on('connect',function(){

    conn.sendText('data')

})
```

Comment: Ну так сертификат-то на сервере какой откуда?

Comment: Я хочу его игнорить

Comment: И плевать на безопасность? Жаль